# org.hibernate.QueryException-- could not resolve property

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee

I have an Entity like below:

```
@Entity
public class Country implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    private Long id;
    @Type(type="secureString") //This is my custom user type and it is working fine in the sense I am able to insert, select and update records using it.
    private SecureString            nationality;
    // getters and setters
}
```

The SecureString class is as below:

```
public class SecureString implements Serializable {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String actualValue;

    private String formattedValue;
    //getters and setters
}
```

`The column name in db for this attibute is named "nationality"`

There is only one column corresponding to nationality. I am making use of Hibernate Custom `UserType` for this. Earlier this property was of type `String` instead of `SecureString`.

I am getting the exception `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: actualValue of: mypackge.Country.`

The HQL formed is :

```
select s FROM mypackage.Country s  
WHERE  LOWER(s.nationality.actualValue) LIKE LOWER(:nationality_actualValue);
```

As per the logs, we can see that Hibernate is trying to find a property with name `actualValue` inside `Country` class while converting HQl to SQl. How do I solve this issue?

NOTE:  I also want that I can use multiple attributes of type SecureString in same Entity class.

Logs:

```
at org.hibernate.QueryException.generateQueryException(QueryException.java:120) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:103) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:217) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:141) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:77) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:153) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:545) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:654) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    ... 142 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: actualValue of: mypackage.Country
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:62) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.toType(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:56) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.toType(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1859) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementType.getPropertyType(FromElementType.java:393) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElement.getPropertyType(FromElement.java:512) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.getDataType(DotNode.java:660) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.prepareLhs(DotNode.java:264) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.resolveInFunctionCall(DotNode.java:178) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.resolve(HqlSqlWalker.java:1030) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.expr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1286) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.exprOrSubquery(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4699) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.functionCall(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2729) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.expr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1361) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.exprOrSubquery(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4699) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.comparisonExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4313) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2134) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2087) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2084) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2084) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2084) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2084) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2062) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.whereClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:813) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:607) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:311) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:259) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:261) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:189) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    ... 148 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Could you post the logs?

Comment: Your `SecureString` is not mapped!?

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto Not getting the point. I have created a Custom UserType and annotated this field by it. What other mapping are you talking about? SecureString is not an Entity.

Comment: @Aldeguer: Logs added

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto Any idea how to solve it? I am still stuck

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a converter, something like this:

```
@Converter
public class SecureConverter implements AttributeConverter<SecureString, String>
{
   @Override
   public String convertToDatabaseColumn(SecureString ss) {
      return ss.getActualValue();
   }
   @Override
   public SecureString convertToEntityAttribute(String s)
   {
      SecureString result = new SecureString();
      result.setActualValue(s);
      return result;
   }
}
```

And use it on your attribute:

```
@Entity
public class Country implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private Long id;
    @Converter(converter = Secureconverter.class)
    private SecureString nationality;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Can we use Converter and Custom UserType together?. Also, Do I need to register this converter somewhere just like I declare UserTypes in package-info.java?